# jQuery .delegate Not Working on Form Load via AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery, delegates

I am submitting and loading a new form via AJAX and want to use the same script that the first form uses to submit and load the new form to submit a comment. I have this script commented out so you cannot see it but when I use it, the `commentForm.php` loads and does not use the jQuery submission. I have tried it many ways with no luck.

```
$('#quoteForm').delegate('input:submit', 'submit',function(e) {
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your form is getting replaced then you'll need to delegate the event handler to a parent element. And you'll need to bind to the *form* and not the submit button:

```
$('body').delegate('form', 'submit', function(e) {

    // and you'll need this to prevent
    // the form's 'default' action
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: That definatly helped me get closer to the desired results.  Here is the link for the page.  http://ab-mobile-apps.com/insuranceapp/html/quoteForm.html  If you can look at the code and let me know what is wrong That would help.  Thank you ahead.

Comment: Hey I got it to work with what you said but used 'click' instead of 'submit'  Thank you